Homotopy of Brown-Gitler spectra
Let $A^\vee = \mathbb{F}_2[\bar\xi_1, \bar\xi_2, ...]$ be the mod-2 dual Steenrod algebra. One can define a weight filtration on $A^\vee$ by setting $wt(\bar\xi_i)=2^i$ and $wt(xy)=wt(x)wt(y)$. There are subcomodules $B_0(k) \subseteq A^\vee$ for each $k \geq 0$ called the Brown-Gitler comodules defined as the span of monomials of weight $\leq k$. These comodules arise as the mod-2 homology of the Brown-Gitler spectra, denoted here as $H\mathbb{Z}_k$; i.e., we have that $H_*(H\mathbb{Z}_k; \mathbb{F}_2) = B_0(k)$.
What are the homotopy groups $\pi_*H\mathbb{Z}_k$? I know that the $H\mathbb{Z}_k$ are finite-cell complexes, but running the Adams-Novikov doesn't seem to give me any substantial information. Any information or direction would be appreciated.

One can essentially never calculate many of the homotopy groups (stable or unstable) of a finite complex.  (When k=2, one is looking at the homotopy groups of the real projective plane.)

In my experience there's a tension between homology and homotopy. Homology "counts cells" so it's simpler for things with few cells. But this makes the homotopy groups blow up in complexity. On the other hand, if you control the homotopy groups, e.g. Eilenberg-MacLane spectra, then the homology becomes very hard to compute.

So in this case you've controlled the homology and lost control of the homotopy groups. The other thing to keep in mind is that to build an EM spectrum you attach a ton of cells.

@NicholasKuhn that is a good point. Thank you for the comment.

@JonathanBeardsley thanks for the comment, the comparison with Eilenberg-Maclane spectra is especially helpful. I was hoping that there might be a slick way to use the fact that they filter bo in homology and turn this into a statement about homotopy, but I guess that's a little too much to ask for.

This is not an answer but perhaps gives interesting context.  The Brown-Gitler spectra are (up to suspension) wedge summands in the spectrum $\Sigma^\infty_+\Omega^2S^3$.  Up to homotopy there is a unique nontrivial double loop map $\alpha\colon\Omega^2S^3\to BO$, which can be regarded as giving a virtual vector bundle over $\Omega^2S^3$.  It is known (I think due to Mahowald) that the Thom spectrum $(\Omega^2S^3)^\alpha$ is just the mod $2$ Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum $H$.  This means that we have a Thom isomorphism $H_*(\Omega^2S^3)_+\simeq H_*H$.  If this was an isomorphism of $H_*H$-comodules then we would have the same Adams Spectral Sequence $E_2$ term for $\Sigma^\infty_+\Omega^2S^3$ and $H$, which would give $\pi_*^S(\Omega^2S^3)_+=\pi^S_0(\Omega^2S^3)_+=\mathbb{Z}/2$.  However, the Thom isomorphism does not in fact preserve comodule structures so this does not work.  Nonetheless, there is a very nice picture of how things fit together, explained in a paper of Steve Mitchell (Power series methods in unoriented cobordism).  There is a standard interpretation of $\operatorname{spec}(H_*H)$ as $\operatorname{Aut}_1(G_a)$, the scheme of automorphisms of the additive formal group of the form $f(x)=\sum_{i\geq 0}a_ix^{2^i}$ with $a_0=1$.  We can also consider the scheme $\operatorname{End}_0(G_a)$ of endomorphisms with $a_0=0$, and this can be identified with $\operatorname{spec}(H_*(\Omega^2S^3)_+))$.  The Steenrod coalgebra structures of $H_*H$ and $H_*(\Omega^2S^3)_+$ correspond to he actions of $\operatorname{Aut}_1(G_a)$ on $\operatorname{Aut}_1(G_a)$ and $\operatorname{End}_0(G_a)$ by right composition.The Thom isomorphism corresponds to the isomorphism $\operatorname{End}_0(G_a)\simeq\operatorname{Aut}_1(G_a)$ given by adding $x$.  One can probably illuminate some features of the Adams Spectral Sequence for $\pi^S_*(\Omega^2S^3_+)$ from this point of view.  However, as Nick Kuhn said, you cannot expect to calculate this completely.  Indeed, the sphere spectrum $S^0$ (which can be regarded as the zeroth Brown-Gitler spectrum) is evidently a retract of $\Sigma^\infty_+\Omega^2S^3$, and we certainly cannot calculate $\pi^S_*(S^0)$.  The calculations should get easier for higher Brown-Gitler spectra, but only by a finite ratio.
